# Rails: select array based on attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails app I need to find all where:

```
balance != nil or 0
pause != true
```

I tried this but it didn't work

```
@foo = Product.all
@foo = @foo.where( "pause != ?", true )
@foo = @foo.where( "balance != ?", 0 )
@foo = @foo.where( "balance != ?", nil )
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you get? An error or an unexpected output?

Comment: i get an empty object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are ending up with an implicit `AND` between all conditions. How about something like

```
@foo = Product.where("pause!=? AND (balance !=? OR balance is not null)", true, 0)
```

Edit: updated to check for `is not null` instead of comparison with `null`.
Refer to the Active Record query interface [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions)

Comment: @muistooshort - didn't realize that. What would you recommend for null checks?

Comment: `balance is not null`, `x = null` and `x != null` are both false for all `x`.